# How to change keybinding to move to next placeholder in TeXShop on Mac

Tags: texshop, auto-completion, shortcut

*I am currently using TeXShop to edit my LaTeX documents on my **Mac**.*

say on my Latex document I write-`\frac` and press **tab**.This will automatically generate- `\frac{|*}{*}` with my cursor where '|' is made. Now, if I want to move to the next place holder, I have to press **Cmd+Ctrl+f**.
How can I change this shortcut so that it works by pressing **tab**.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the TeXShop help on Command Completion:

> Since moving from mark to mark is often required, TeXShop supports additional keyboard shortcuts beyond those listed in the Completion/Marks menu. When the escape key is used to trigger command completion, option-escape will move to the next mark and control-escape will move to the previous mark. When the tab key triggers command completion, option-tab moves to the next mark and control-tab moves to the previous mark. If you use a third party utility with other uses for these shortcuts, the TeXShop shortcuts can be turned off with a hidden preference. See the "Hidden Preference Items" section of TeXShop Help.

So since you're using Tab you can also use option-tab to move to the next mark, and control-tab to move to the previous mark.  I don't think there's any other choice you can make, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, this is better than Cmd+Ctrl+f